# Trying to use github guillotine menu

Tags: github, build, menu, nullpointerexception

I try to add to my application a menu that I found on Github "Guillotine Menu" with this code:

```
toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    root = findViewById(R.id.root);
    contentHamburger = findViewById(R.id.contentHamburger);

    if (toolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
    }

    View guillotineMenu = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.guillotine, null);
    root.addView(guillotineMenu);

    new GuillotineAnimation.GuillotineBuilder(guillotineMenu, guillotineMenu.findViewById(R.id.guillotine_hamburger), contentHamburger)
            .setStartDelay(RIPPLE_DURATION)
            .setActionBarViewForAnimation(toolbar)
            .setClosedOnStart(true)
            .build();`
```

But I have an error and I can't solve it :

```
`Unable to start activity  :  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to 
invoke virtual method 'void 
android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on 
a null object reference 
at david.ouiz.project5.MapsActivity2.onCreate(MapsActivity2.java:125)`
```

This line (125) refers to the 
    `".build()"` function.

Can anybody help me ??

Thank you very much